# Can not open SPP in android studio

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, spp

I am new to Android Studio and Ubuntu. I downloaded SPP App from GitHub, and when I tried to open it in Android Studio, I found that the file is not listed in the folder chooser in Android Studio. When I checked the folder containing that file on the hard drive, I found that this folder was marked with a locker sign.

Is the file not getting opened in the studio because it is marked with a locker sign? How to solve this issue?

The link to SPP APP is:

```
https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary
```

Comment: @StephanBranczyk thanks for ur comment. and yes it was zipped file and i unzipped it in the downloads directory

Comment: I've posted my solution as an answer then. I'd suggest you accept one of our answers by ticking the checkmark next to an answer. But do note that Ådəəl Åhmåd's solution to use gradle is the best practice for importing a library project like Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary. You should ultimately learn to use his solution for importing a library. And I wouldn't be offended if you picked his answer over mine when accepting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The app you are trying to use is an external Library. To integrate it in your project and use its features , add `compile 'com.akexorcist:bluetoothspp:1.0.0'`  in your "build.gradle" file in "dependencies" section (will be in the end of build.gradle file ) , it'll look like this :

```
dependencies {

    //..other dependencies
    compile 'com.akexorcist:bluetoothspp:1.0.0'

}
```

android studio will automatically download and integrate this in your project.

Answer (score 0):

From our exchange in the comments, the problem was that the file was zipped.

Unzipping it solved the issue.